# Vue + Pinia data storage and retrieval

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I'm studying Vue and Pinia. I ran into such a problem that I don't know how to work better with data on the user side. On the main page, I display categories and auction items, when you go to the catalog page for a certain category, data about auction items remain in the store and are also displayed on this page, although they may not belong to this category. Which approach is better to use when working with data?

I have such a Store.

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ProductState } from "@/entities/product/api/model/ProductState";
import { ProductActions } from "@/entities/product/api/model/Actions";
import { Product } from "@/entities/product/model/Product";
import { PageableType } from "@/shared/pageable/pageableType";
import Characteristics from "@/entities/product/model/Characteristics";
import categoriesCard from "@/entities/categories/ui/CategoriesCard.vue";

export const storeModule = defineStore("product", {
  state: (): ProductState => ({
    product: {} as Product,
    pages: [] as PageableType<Product>[],
    isRequestLoading: true,
  }),
  getters: {
    getProducts(state) {
      return (pageNumber: number) =>
        state.pages.find((value) => value.number === pageNumber);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async loadProduct(pageNumber: number, pageSize: number) {
      this.isRequestLoading = true;
      const res = await ProductActions.loadProduct(pageNumber, pageSize);
      console.log(res);
      this.updateProducts(res);
      this.isRequestLoading = false;
    },

    async loadProductByCategories(
      pageNumber: number,
      pageSize: number,
      categoriesId: number
    ) {
      this.isRequestLoading = true;
      const res = await ProductActions.loadProductByCategories(
        pageNumber,
        pageSize,
        categoriesId
      );
      console.log(res);
      this.updateProducts(res);
      this.isRequestLoading = false;
    },

    async loadProductInPromotion(pageNumber: number, pageSize: number) {
      this.isRequestLoading = true;
      const res = await ProductActions.loadProductInPromotion(
        pageNumber,
        pageSize
      );
      this.updateProducts(res);
      this.isRequestLoading = false;
    },

    updateProducts(payload: PageableType<Product>) {
      this.pages.push(payload);
    },
  },
});
```

I understand that the problem is very easily solved by changing this part of the code. But I don't want to contact the server every time the catalog page is changed, but first check the data on the user part.

```
updateProducts(payload: PageableType<Product>) {
      this.pages.push(payload);
    },
```

Does it make sense to create a bunch of variables in State for each criterion (Auction, Products in a certain category, Products suitable for a certain filter). I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: It might be handy to keep all the products in the `pages` array, but just adjust your filter in your getter to reflect categories or (ignoring) auction items. In other words, I would first look at that getter. Unless I'm missing some details.

Comment: The problem is that I get the data from the server as a page. And to check, as for me, there will be too much nesting and this construction, as for me, will not be very readable. It will turn out something like this:
`getPages: (status) => {
      return (page number: number) =>
        state.pages.find((page) => {
          return (
page.content.find((product) => product.categories.id === Category ID) &&
page.number == page number
          );
        });
    },`

Comment: The problem is mainly that the store is not cleared when changing pages.

Comment: The store not clearing between page changes (not refresh) is actually the desired behavior. If you do want that, you will need to manually clear it on page change, with some kind of action in the store and a https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#Per-Route-Guard

Comment: It's just that I used Vuex before, but decided to try Pinia. And here I do not understand how to correctly beat this logic. All work with my data takes place on the server and I receive them ready-made and in a pegeable wrapper. Because of this, I don't understand how to store and interact with them.

Comment: If you're around, let's chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256978/vue-pinia-data-storage-and-retrieval I'll be in there for a bit.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Ok, no worries. Try creating an action, something like `clearPages() { this.pages = [] }`. In your `router` file import this action and call it at the route for the page, either in `beforeEnter` or `beforeLeave`, depending on what you need. See the page I linked in a earlier comment as guide.

Comment: Let me know if it works, then I can add it as an answer and you can then accept it :) I could use the points hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the `pages` state "manually".

1: Create an action, something like

```js
clearPages() { this.pages = [] }
```

2: Call this action whenever the route to that page changes. Depending on your design, either when you enter the page or when you leave, or both. This can be done in the `router` file, where you define the route, or in the component.
Read more about [Navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to see how to get this done.